# Python how to search through all the files in a directoy

Tags: python, file, search, directory, cpu-word

I would like to search for a word in all the files in a directory.

Eg.:
I have a folder "Test Directory" and in it I have 5 files

`TestFile1.txt` ... `TestFile5.txt`

Let's say only one of them contains a specific word `Test` written inside it. How can I search through all of them until I find the one with the word?

Comment: please take a look on `glob` module : https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0):

You should go with some full search engines like Elasticsearch and use python to query over Elasticsearch. But if you doing this one-time, then you take help from below code.

```
for file in glob.glob("/folder/path/*.txt"):
    if 'word' in open(file).read():
            print(file)
```